# Run wall command as another user RHEL8

Tags: rhel, sudo

How do I send a wall message as root (or any other user) and it not identify the original user?

Looking at the below I would have expected wall to display message from root but it still shows admin1, what am I missing?

I have tried various sudo -i, -s, using -c to send command, tmux, runuser but always the same result. Is it a global setting in sudoers or something else?

For context this was a question on a test I couldn't figure out and not been given an answer!

```
 [admin1@RHELPOC ~]$ sudo su - [root@RHELPOC ~]# id uid=0(root)
 gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
 context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
 [root@RHELPOC ~]# wall "whoisthis"
 
 Broadcast message from admin1@RHELPOC (pts/0) (Fri Jan  8 13:58:40
 2021): whoisthis
```

Comment: A workaround that works for me in Debian 10: `echo 'wall "whoisthis"' | sudo at now`.

Answer (score 0):

`wall` uses `getlogin` to get the username for the message and fallbacks to `getpwuid` only when `getlogin` call fails (see [here](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/term-utils/wall.c#L357)).

`getlogin` returns *name of the user logged in on the controlling terminal of the process* (from [getlogin manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getlogin.3.html)) and `su` only runs a shell with user and group ID 0 and even with `su -` it's not a "login shell" so it doesn't change the result of `getlogin`: *Start  the shell as a login shell with an environment similar to a real login* (from [su manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html)).

`getpwuid(getuid())` actually returns the "correct" user, but that's called only when the `getlogin` call fails.

So to get `wall` "from root" you actually need to login as root on TTY. You should also be able to login using the `login` command but this doesn't seem to be working for me from terminal on Fedora.

Edit: Not sure what's broken in my Fedora, `login` is working as expected in an Ubuntu VM:

```
vtrefny@ubuntu:~$ sudo login
ubuntu login: root
Password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-58-generic x86_64)

...

root@ubuntu:~# wall "aaaa"
                                                                               
Broadcast message from root@ubuntu (pts/0) (Fri Jan  8 21:57:39 2021):         
                                                                               
aaaa
```

So the answer is to use `login` on a system that works :-)